# Random ID every page

Tags: php, pdo

I want create button what gives every link unique link ID from database.

I have only button "Next" what should give me next story page.

I didn't find any snippet from google how to create link with ID what doesn't duplicate later.

My code:

```
$row = Db::run()->pdoQuery('SELECT c.name AS name
, p.id AS id, p.created AS created
, p.title AS title, p.body AS body, p.cover AS cover 
FROM projects AS p 
INNER JOIN categories AS c 
  ON p.category = c.id 
WHERE p.id ="' . $id . '";')->results(); // for current story article

$nrow = Db::run()->pdoQuery('SELECT 
    (SELECT MIN(id) AS id FROM projects WHERE id > p.id) as next_id, 
    (SELECT title FROM projects WHERE id > p.id) as next_title,
    (SELECT cover FROM projects WHERE id > p.id) as next_cover,
    (SELECT c.name AS name FROM projects AS a 
        INNER JOIN categories AS c 
          ON a.category = c.id 
     WHERE a.id > p.id) AS next_name
FROM projects p WHERE p.id = "' . $id . '"')->results(); // for next story article


$tpl->data = $row;
$tpl->next = $nrow;
```

"Next story" button image:
[Next story](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhhkD.png)

Maybe is possible somehow it checks what ID was last time given and whats current and whats next coming or cache it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using MySQL queries in your question.

You could update your database schema such that your `projects` table has a column with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` flag.

From [their docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html):

> "The AUTO_INCREMENT attribute can be used to generate a unique identity for new rows"

Then, when saving a new row to that table, you can omit the `id` column or specify `NULL`, if the schema says `NOT NULL` to have the auto increment take place. This will prevent identity collisions, however they are not RANDOM.

For that, you might consider using [`UUID()` or `UUID_SHORT()` in MySQL 5.7+](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-short).

Additionally, though your Q implies that you're not using an ORM, tools like [Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/) & [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions) give quick access to more random, (and more SEO-friendly) unique ID options for rows, like [slugs](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/search?q=Sluggable&unscoped_q=Sluggable).

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer you are looking for - but you'll need to be a lot more specific if you want a specific answer.

> gives every link unique link ID from database

That's impossible unless you have more stories in your database than will ever be read - which is a bit silly. It makes a bit more sense if you mean that one person will not see the same id more than once. But do you mean once in a session? For as long as they have an account? Do you want to provide this as an anonymous capability people can use without an account?

You don't say of the order in which IDs are presented is relevant.

You didn't say what the data type of 'projects.id' is.

Your query for the next story makes no sense at all.

Assuming stories will read in order, and you are not retaining state serverside, and you have ensured compliance with local provacy laws and that project.id is a near contiguous set of integers, and that this is a web-based application (a LOT of assumptions) then just drop a cookie containing the ID each time you present a story, then get the next story with...

```
 SELECT c.name AS name
 , p.id AS id, p.created AS created
 , p.title AS title, p.body AS body, p.cover AS cover 
 FROM projects AS p 
 INNER JOIN categories AS c 
   ON p.category = c.id 
 WHERE p.id =(SELECT MIN(read.id) 
    FROM projects read
    WHERE id>" . (integer) $_COOKIE['lastread']
```